# Node.js serialize and deserialize YAML with comments

Tags: node.js, serialization, yaml

I'm making a config reading/writing system and I want to be able to read and write YAML to a file and serialize it with comments.

I want to use the config in memory as a Javascript object and store it in a file as YAML.

Is there any package for Node.js that does this?

I have tried [js-yaml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-yaml) & [yaml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yaml) but to my knowledge they don't support comment serialization, instead they just ignore comments.